# Multiple cherrypy webapps on one server with apache serving other PHP projects?

Tags: python, cherrypy

When I work in PHP I can work on seperate projects in different folders and run them by just pointing to the domain/folder. Is there a way to run cherrypy app in similar way? Basically I have a apache server I use for running my website. I use the same server to develop and test other PHP projects. Can I also easily use the same server for running multiple cherrypy applications or maybe different Python framework would allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/ModWSGI

Basically, you have to set the engine to run in embedded mode. That's the python side.

The Apache side is covered in mod_wsgi discussions, but basically you create a virtual host with this directive

```
WSGIScriptAlias /path/to/script.py
```

You should be able to run as many virtualhosts with that as you want, although I haven't tested it.